# Training Neural Network with Keras and Large Array Numpy

Tags: keras, tf.keras, large-data, mmap, unet-neural-network

I want to train an UNET Network and my data is already normalized in an Array, I saved it in my disk in bin format, it's about 12GB of data. My memory is limited so I need to load a batch of the data train, and after clear and load another batch to train, but I am not founding how to do this while training is happening. I would like to use Keras and not pytorch cause my program is already all in keras, but if the best way would be pytorch I will change my things. I hope someone can help me.

I tried to use memmap before training, importing the mmap data but keras didn't recognized it.

check the images:

- importing mmaps

```py
        
    from mmap_ninja.ragged import RaggedMmap
    X_train_mmp = RaggedMmap('/kaggle/working/xTreino_mmap')
    y_train_cat_mmp = RaggedMmap('/kaggle/working/yTreino_mmap')
    X_test_mmp = RaggedMmap('/kaggle/working/xTeste_mmap')
    y_test_cat_mmp = RaggedMmap('/kaggle/working/yTeste_mmap')
```

- trying to training

```py
              
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[14], line 1
    ----> 1 history = model.fit(X_train_mmp, y_train_cat_mmp, 
    2                     batch_size = 8, 
    3                     verbose=1, 
    4                     epochs=10, 
    5                     validation_data=(X_test_mmp, y_test_cat_mmp), 
    6                     shuffle=False)
    File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
    ---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    71 finally:
    72     del filtered_tb
    
    File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py:1082, in select_data_adapter(x, y)
    1079 adapter_cls = [cls for cls in ALL_ADAPTER_CLS if cls.can_handle(x, y)]
    1080 if not adapter_cls:
    1081     # TODO(scottzhu): This should be a less implementation-specific error.
    -> 1082     raise ValueError(
    1083         "Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: {}, {}".format(
    1084             _type_name(x), _type_name(y)
    1085         )
    1086     )
    1087 elif len(adapter_cls) > 1:
    1088     raise RuntimeError(
    1089         "Data adapters should be mutually exclusive for "
    1090         "handling inputs. Found multiple adapters {} to handle "
    1091 "input: {}, {}".format(adapter_cls, _type_name(x), _type_name(y))
    1092     )
    ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'mmap_ninja.ragged.RaggedMmap'>, <class   'mmap_ninja.ragged.RaggedMmap'>
```

Comment: You could use either of the suggestions in this thread: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47623/how-feed-a-numpy-array-in-batches-in-keras

Comment: Please don't post your errors/outputs as links/screenshots.